# if statement in class attribute definiton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to make if statement in a class Definition?

`<Card className={${css.processStepInstanceCard}}>`

I want to add a second css class if a var is true.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
<Card className={bool ? css.processStepInstanceCard :  css.anotherClass}>
```

Comment: tried it this way `<Card className={this.props.step.status === "done" ? css.processStepInstanceCard : `${css.processStepInstanceCard} ${css.done}`}>` but dosn't work

Comment: You mean? <Card className={this.props.step.status === "done" ? css.processStepInstanceCard : \`${css.processStepInstanceCard}  ${css.done}\`>

Comment: yes that is exactly what I had, the comment removed the back-ticks. But the css.done class isn't added when condition=true

Comment: you can print the value of the expression for debugging

Comment: result = `App--processStepInstanceCard--1dLxb44a` ... just the first css class is added.

Comment: logical problem ;) thanks